# Como hacer un conteo de cuantos datos se guardaron en el mes y si no hay que coloque cero

Tags: mysql

Quiero que en mi consulta me muestre cuantos datos se guardaron en el mes y si no hay en ese mes que aparezcan cero en esos meses (me muestra bien cuantos se guardaron pero no me muestra los meses sin datos)

```
SELECT COUNT(Tipo_mante ) AS Cantidad, MONTHNAME(fecha_soli) AS mes
from solicitud_mante 
WHERE Estado = 'Pendiente'
AND Tipo_Mante = 'Predictivo'
GROUP BY Tipo_mante, YEAR(fecha_soli), MONTH(fecha_soli)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya lo probe con un case pero nada haber si me pude ayudar con esta duda

Comment: podrias mostrarnos los datos de tu tabla? tenes una tabla para meses en otro lado?

Comment: No en la misma tabla guardo la fecha automáticamente cuando se guarda cualquier registro todo eso es en la misma tabla

Comment: Entonces no podes mostrar un count sobre 0, cuando no hay registros que contar. SQL no puede "inventar" registros. Necesitas una tabla con los meses. Podes mostrar el formato de la tabla, asi podemos hacerte una respuesta.

Comment: Es como te dice @gbianchi, deberías tener una tabla de Periodos, con un id que sea año + mes. Si la tienes, agrega la definición de la misma. Sino la única alternativa es generar dinamicamente los periodos que necesites.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho estoy tentado de marcarla como dup de la respuesta que diste hace minutos.. es casi lo mismo... Es mas.. no se si no deberiamos hacer una pregunta canonica al respecto de como contar registros que no existen...

Comment: @gbianchi, justo iba a comentarte como a veces ciertas problemáticas se repiten en tan corto tiempo. No creo que sea duplicada exacta de esa, pero el problema conceptual es idéntico. De hecho habría que escarbar un poco, ya debe haber algunas preguntas sobre como generar períodos de forma dinámica. Lo de la pregunta canónica estaría bueno, sin duda es una temática repetitiva, y que además genera respuesta erróneas rápidamente, por que no se llega a ver el problema, lo pienso un poco.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho creo que si nos ponemos a buscar los dos lo contestamos varias veces ya...

Comment: @gbianchi, fijate esto a ver que te parece: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270497/como-listar-ventas-de-periodos-de-los-que-no-tengo-informaci%C3%B3n/270498#270498, me fata agregarle una opción para generar los períodos de forma dinámica.