# ¿Cómo listar ventas de periodos de los que no tengo información?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla de ventas mensual como la siguiente:

```
create table ventas (
  id      int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  year    int,
  month   int,
  monto numeric(15,2),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);  

insert into ventas (year, month, monto) values (2018, 1, 100);
insert into ventas (year, month, monto) values (2018, 1, 300);
insert into ventas (year, month, monto) values (2018, 3, 340);
insert into ventas (year, month, monto) values (2018, 5, 200);
insert into ventas (year, month, monto) values (2018, 5, 100);
insert into ventas (year, month, monto) values (2018, 7, 100);
insert into ventas (year, month, monto) values (2018, 8, 100);
insert into ventas (year, month, monto) values (2018, 9, 200);
insert into ventas (year, month, monto) values (2018,11, 350);
insert into ventas (year, month, monto) values (2018,12, 440);
```

Estoy tratando de hacer un reporte de estas ventas por mes, lo intenté así:

```
select year,
       month,
       sum(monto) as total
       from ventas
       group by year,
                month
```

Y obtengo algo como esto:

```
| year | month | total |
|------|-------|-------|
| 2018 |     1 |   400 |
| 2018 |     3 |   340 |
| 2018 |     5 |   300 |
| 2018 |     7 |   100 |
| 2018 |     8 |   100 |
| 2018 |     9 |   200 |
| 2018 |    11 |   350 |
| 2018 |    12 |   440 |
```

Lo cual es correcto, pero como se puede observar hay "huecos", es decir, meses sin valores, quisiera tener un reporte, pero con los 12 meses y completar los que no han tenido ventas con un 0, es decir algo así

```
| year | month | total |
|------|-------|-------|
| 2018 |     1 |   400 |
| 2018 |     2 |     0 |
| 2018 |     3 |   340 |
| 2018 |     4 |     0 |
| 2018 |     5 |   300 |
| 2018 |     6 |     0 |
| 2018 |     7 |   100 |
| 2018 |     8 |   100 |
| 2018 |     9 |   200 |
| 2018 |    10 |     0 |
| 2018 |    11 |   350 |
| 2018 |    12 |   440 |
```

#### Importante

Puede que no sean ventas, o que sea algún otro tipo de datos, es importante entender el problema conceptual, que es, ¿qué hacemos cuando nos falta información en una tabla?. Cuando no tenemos lecturas de un sensor para todas las horas, cuando hay cuentas contables que no registran movimientos en ciertos meses, cuando queremos listar las ventas de todas las sucursales, pero hay sucursales que no han tenido ventas, cuando queremos saber cuantas personas ocuparon una habitación, pero hay habitaciones que nunca han sido ocupadas, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Antes de intentar cualquier cosa extraña, hay que tener en claro que nos faltan datos, no tenemos información para los meses 2, 4, 6 y 10. Por lo que no existe magia posible para solucionar esto. Cualquier solución que encaremos, lo primero que habrá que hacer es "inventar" estas filas que no tenemos. Y entonces **¿Cómo "inventamos" las filas que nos faltan?**. Para mi gusto, la mejor alternativa es:

#### Manejar una tabla de períodos

¿No la tienes? Es un buen momento para crearla, créeme que estas tablas son tremendamente útiles. Por ejemplo, un forma de tabla de períodos bastante flexible sería:

```
create table Periodos (
  PeriodoId  int,
  Tipo       char(1),
  Nombre     varchar(100),
  FechaDesde date,
  FechaHasta date,
  PRIMARY KEY (PeriodoId, Tipo)
);  

insert into Periodos(PeriodoId, Tipo, Nombre, FechaDesde, FechaHasta)
SELECT 201801, 'M', 'Enero/2018', '20180101', '20180201' UNION
SELECT 201802, 'M', 'Febrero/2018', '20180201', '20180301' UNION
SELECT 201803, 'M', 'Marzo/2018', '20180301', '20180401' UNION
SELECT 201804, 'M', 'Abril/2018', '20180401', '20180501' UNION
SELECT 201805, 'M', 'Mayo/2018', '20180501', '20180601' UNION
SELECT 201806, 'M', 'Junio/2018', '20180601', '20180701' UNION
SELECT 201807, 'M', 'Julio/2018', '20180701', '20180801' UNION
SELECT 201808, 'M', 'Agosto/2018', '20180801', '20180901' UNION
SELECT 201809, 'M', 'Septiembre/2018', '20180901', '20181001' UNION
SELECT 201810, 'M', 'Octubre/2018', '20181001', '20181101' UNION
SELECT 201811, 'M', 'Noviembre/2018', '20181101', '20181201' UNION
SELECT 201812, 'M', 'Diciembre/2018', '20181201', '20190101';
```

- `PeriodId`: sera nuestro `id` del período, lo importante es que respete el orden de los periodos, de forma tal que ordenando por esta columna, obtengamos el orden natural de los períodos
- `Tipo`: Un "lujo" que nos podemos permitir, para manejar distintos tipos de períodos, por ejemplo `M` para periodos mensuales, podría ser `Y` para llevar periodos anuales, `S` para llevar periodos semanales, `F` para períodos fiscales, etc.
- El `Nombre` es simplemente la descripción que vamos a mostrar
- `FechaDesde` y `FechaHasta` son útiles cuando, por ejemplo, tenemos que obtener un período dada una fecha, que `FechaHasta` tenga un día más, es simplemente una ayuda para que funcione perfecto el `BETWEEN`

Ahora que tenemos esta tabla de períodos, es sumamente sencillo resolver este problema. En realidad lo que tenemos que pensar, es que el problema conceptual es: (a) listar todos los períodos (b) obtener el total de ventas de cada uno:

```
select p.PeriodoId,
       p.Nombre,
       ifnull(sum(v.monto),0) as total
       from Periodos P
       left join ventas v
          on P.PeriodoId = (v.year*100) + v.month
       where p.tipo = 'M'
       group by p.PeriodoId,
                p.Nombre;
```

Y ahora si:

```
| PeriodoId |          Nombre | total |
|-----------|-----------------|-------|
|    201801 |      Enero/2018 |   400 |
|    201802 |    Febrero/2018 |     0 |
|    201803 |      Marzo/2018 |   340 |
|    201804 |      Abril/2018 |     0 |
|    201805 |       Mayo/2018 |   300 |
|    201806 |      Junio/2018 |     0 |
|    201807 |      Julio/2018 |   100 |
|    201808 |     Agosto/2018 |   100 |
|    201809 | Septiembre/2018 |   200 |
|    201810 |    Octubre/2018 |     0 |
|    201811 |  Noviembre/2018 |   350 |
|    201812 |  Diciembre/2018 |   440 |
```

- Necesitamos hacer `ifnull(sum(v.monto),0)` para poner un 0 en aquellos períodos que no tengamos ventas.
- En el `join` hacemos `on P.PeriodoId = (v.year*100) + v.month` para generar desde un año y mes el id con el que hemos definido el período. Es una forma, también podrías manejar una tabla de períodos más sencilla solo con años y meses

**Importante**: Debes generar las tablas de períodos para cubrir el universo completo razonable de casos. Por ejemplo, ¿cual es tu primer fecha registrada en en el sistema? ¿Cual es la última? a esos límites agrégales unos cuanto periodos más hacia arriba y hacia abajo, los suficientes para  no tener problemas futuros (o al menos no estar vivo cuando vengan los reclamos).

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cf09a4/8)**

Comment: Muy bien explicado

Comment: Como siempre un maestro en estas lides. Saludos

Answer (score 7):

Esta otra alternativa esta orientada a:

- Consultas muy sencillas y puntuales que no ameriten manejar una tabla de períodos
- No tengamos los derechos ni posibilidades de tocar la estructura de la base de datos
- O a que simplemente tengamos "pereza"

Ya dijimos, que nos faltan meses, también que la mejor forma es contar con una tabla de períodos no? sino podemos hacer esto, de todas formas deberemos generar los períodos de alguna forma dinámica que nos sirva. Veamos algunas posibilidades:

#### Simple

Solo para algo sencillo, donde listamos un año completo, podemos crear de forma dura una consulta que nos retorne los 12 meses que necesitamos:

```
select p.mes,
       ifnull(sum(v.monto),0) as total
       from (select 1 as mes union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union 
             select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 10 union 
             select 11 union select 12) P
       left join ventas v
             on v.month = p.mes
             and v.year = 2018
       group by p.mes;
```

#### ¿Y para más de un año?

Acá es donde vas a lamentar no poder o no querer crear la tabla de períodos. Generar estos períodos dinámicamente, cuando son mas que los doce meses anteriores, requiere generar una secuencia dinámica para los años, lo cual no es algo natural, o digamos que no forma parte de la especificación SQL. Una forma que conceptualmente es compatible con todas las bases (con ligeras diferencias) es hacer productos cartesianos entre tablas de 10 elementos y así ir multiplicando de 10 en diez, por ejemplo, para generar 1000 años, desde 1900 al 2900, se podría hacer así:

```
SELECT @year := @year + 1 AS year
       FROM (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t1
       CROSS JOIN (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t2
       CROSS JOIN (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t3
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT @year:=1900) t
```

Y ahora si, juntamos todo, los meses, los años y las ventas:

```
select p.year,
       p.month,
       ifnull(sum(v.monto),0) as total
       FROM (
              SELECT y.year,
                     m.month
                    FROM (SELECT @year := @year + 1 AS year
                                FROM (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t1
                                CROSS JOIN (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t2
                                CROSS JOIN (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t3
                                CROSS JOIN (SELECT @year:=1900) t0
                          ) y
                    CROSS JOIN (select month 
                                      FROM (select 1 as month union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union 
                                            select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 10 union 
                                            select 11 union select 12) doce
                                ) m
       ) p
       left join ventas v
          on P.year = v.year
          and p.month = v.month
       WHERE p.year = 2018
       GROUP BY p.year,
                p.month
       ORDER BY p.year,
                p.month;
```

La salida debiera ser idéntica a la respuesta anterior usando tabla de períodos, pero claramente mucho más compleja y complicada de leer.

Nota: 
**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cf09a4/17)**